# Prove that $\bar{a}\bar{b} = \bar{b}\bar{a}$ if and only if $a^{-1}b^{-1}ab \in N$

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $G$ be a group, $N \triangleleft G$ and $\bar{G} = G/N$.  Prove that for every two elements $\bar{a},\bar{b} \in \bar{G}$, the following is true: $\bar{a}\bar{b} = \bar{b}\bar{a}$ if and only if $a^{-1}b^{-1}ab \in N$.

I am having trouble with quotient groups and the textbook does not help me simplify.  I am struggling to see the connection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it might be easier if you change your notation. Denote $\bar{a} = aN$. In general, $xN = yN$ means that $y^{-1}x\in N$, then: $$abN = baN \leftrightarrow a^{-1}b^{-1}abN = N \leftrightarrow a^{-1}b^{-1}ab \in N.$$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

By the definition of $G/N$, equality is defined as $\bar x = \bar y$ in $\bar G$ if and only if $xy^{-1} \in N$.